# Create a Summarized report using Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, sql

My Table is like

```
| Cat | Sub_Cat | Amt|
______________________
 X    | Y       | 200
_______________________
 X    | Z       | 1000
__________________________
 X    | Y       | 300
__________________________
 A    | B       | 600
```

Now i want to write a query where i can Show a summarized report which is grouped by category like this output

```
| Cat | Sub_Cat | Amt|
______________________
 X    | Y       | 500
_______________________
 X    | Z       | 1000
__________________________
 A    | B       | 600
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  Cat,
  Sub_Cat,
  SUM(Amt) as total
FROM
  my_table
GROUP BY
  Cat,
  Sub_Cat
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.cat, t.sub_cat, sum(t.amt) from table t
group by t.cat, t.sub_cat
```